# Reformat JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, format

I have a JSON file of the following format:

```
[
{"url": "example1.com", "date": "Jan 1", "text": "Example text 1"},
{"url": "example2.com", "date": "Jan 2", "text": "Example text 2"}
]
```

Which I upload into Python using:

```py
with open("data.json") as data:
    data = json.load(data)
```

I would like to reformat the uploaded data to the following format:

```
[
   (
    "Example text 1", 
    {"url": "example1.com", "date": "Jan 1"}
   ),
   (
    "Example text 2", 
    {"url": "example2.com", "date": "Jan 2"}
   )
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
data = [
{"url": "example1.com", "date": "Jan 1", "text": "Example text 1"},
{"url": "example2.com", "date": "Jan 2", "text": "Example text 2"}
]

# make tuples
[(d.pop('text'), d) for d in data]

# [('Example text 1', {'url': 'example1.com', 'date': 'Jan 1'}),
#  ('Example text 2', {'url': 'example2.com', 'date': 'Jan 2'})]
```